# Lazy loading in primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a component with p-dropdown and p-table. When I choose item in the dropdown i would like to lazy load data in my p-table in this component. Is it possibile? When I'm trying i have only lazy load on init whole component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablelazy-demo-lwb4no?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the example you provided:

1. An error is thrown because the `event` parameter in your
   onChange function is undefined.
   To fix this you need to call the function in the template like this:

```html
<p-dropdown
  [options]="['customers_a', 'customers_b', 'customers_c']"
  (onChange)="onChange($event)"
></p-dropdown>
```

(Mind the dollar sign in the parameter name. You can find more about this in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding))

2. You are not providing a lazy load event to the `loadCustomers` method. Instead you are passing the event from the dropdown which does not have the required attributes.

So instead of calling the `loadCustomers` method like this:

```
    this.loadCustomers(event, this.selectedCustomers);
```

You can either call the `reset` method on the table or manually get the lazyLoad metadata from the table.
In order to do this you need a reference to the table in you component class.
This can be archive with the [ViewChield](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator.

Option 1:

```
  @ViewChild(Table)
  table: Table;

  onChange(event) {
    this.selectedCustomers = event.value;
    this.table.reset()
  }
```

Option 2:

```
  @ViewChild(Table)
  table: Table;

  onChange(event) {
    this.selectedCustomers = event.value;
    this.loadCustomers(this.table.createLazyLoadMetadata(), this.selectedCustomers)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way I've found to do this is just to induce the load yourself.

If you have a component method called `onLazyLoad` that's acting as the `onLazyLoad` callback:

```
onLazyLoad(event: LazyLoadEvent) { . . . }

<p-table
    (onLazyLoad)="onLazyLoad($event)"
</p-table>
```

You can just request an event from the table then call your callback with that:

```
triggerLazyLoad(): void {
  // this.table is a ViewChild of the p-table in the template
  const lazyLoadEvent = this.table.createLazyLoadMetadata();
  this.onLazyLoad(lazyLoadEvent);
}
```

Now, `createLazyLoadMetadata` isn't technically documented, but it is public. Not the greatest solution, but there doesn't appear to be a good way to trigger a lazy load in response to something like an external filter changing.